# How to catch CTabView close button pressed?

Tags: c++, mfc, tabview

I'm writing an app in MFC with tabs. I'm extending `CTabView` class with my own.
I want to catch event while closing active tab and actually remove it from TabView.
The message `WM_LBUTTONUP` is never handled here - it's not handlen in ANY child class - what am I doing wrong?
Where I can catch event when I'm closing active tab?

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CBottomTabView, CTabView)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CBottomTabView, CTabView)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CBottomTabView::CBottomTabView()
{
}

CBottomTabView::~CBottomTabView()
{
}


BOOL CBottomTabView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs) 
{
    if (!CTabView::PreCreateWindow(cs))
        return FALSE;

    cs.dwExStyle |= WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
    cs.style &= ~WS_BORDER;
    cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_DBLCLKS, 
        ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW+1), NULL);

    return TRUE;
}

int CBottomTabView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CTabView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    GetTabControl().SetLocation(CMFCBaseTabCtrl::LOCATION_BOTTOM);
    GetTabControl().ModifyTabStyle(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D_ONENOTE);
    GetTabControl().EnableTabDocumentsMenu(TRUE);
    GetTabControl().EnableActiveTabCloseButton(TRUE);
    GetTabControl().EnableTabSwap(TRUE);

    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CLogView),_T("Log"));
    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CLogView),_T("Log2"));
    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CLogView),_T("Log3"));
    return 0;
}

// This method is never handled!!!
void CBottomTabView::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    int nTab = GetTabControl().GetTabFromPoint(point);
    GetTabControl().SetActiveTab(nTab);
    if (GetTabControl().IsTabCloseButtonPressed())
    {
        RemoveView(nTab);
    }
    else
    {
        CTabView::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
    }

}

// This metod is handled only when changing the tab
void CBottomTabView::OnActivateView(CView* view)
{
    CTabView::OnActivateView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've asked for the OnLButtonDown event in your message map, not the OnLButtonUp event which you're reacting to. Either change the message map, or change your function.

Comment: sorry, I was also trying OnLButtonDown, and forgot to change it back. I've changed back my message map - it still has no effect.